# Codeigniter: How to fix pagination links, not updating when clicked, using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

I'm trying to put pagination links into my website using ajax to keep the page from refreshing. I managed to make it work but the pagination links are not updating. When I click on the next page, the page will load but the pagination link will stay on page 1. I tried putting `$this->pagination->create_links();` inside a variable and echo it inside a div but its showing nothing. Here are my codes:

model:

```
public function get_posts($limit = FALSE, $rowno = FALSE)
        {
            if($limit)
            {
                $this->db->limit($limit, $rowno);
            }

            $this->db->select('*, posts.image AS post_image, posts.id AS post_id, posts.user_id AS post_user_id');
            $this->db->from('posts');
            $this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id = posts.category_id');
            $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = posts.user_id');
            $this->db->order_by('posts.created_at', 'DESC');

            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result_array();
        }
```

controller:

```
public function index()
        {
            // pagination page number
            $pageno = $this->input->post('pageno');

            // pagination config
            // $config['base_url'] = base_url()."posts/index";
            $config['base_url'] = '#';
            $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('posts');
            $config['per_page'] = 2;
            $config['num_links'] = 3;
            $config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'pagination-class');
            $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="paginator">';
            $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

            $data['posts'] = $this->post_model->get_posts($config['per_page'], $pageno);
            $data['title'] = 'Latest Posts';

            $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
            $data['row'] = $pageno;

            // init pagination
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            $this->load->view('posts/index', $data);

        }
```

view:

```
<div id="pagination">
            <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
    </div>
```

ajax:

```
$('#paginator').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var pageno = $(this).attr('data-ci-pagination-page');

        $.ajax({
            data : { 'pageno' : pageno },
            method : 'post',
            // dataType : 'json',
            url : base_url + 'posts/index',
            success : function(response) {
                $("#main_container").html(response);
            }
        });
```

Comment: have you load library of pagination like `$this->load->library('pagination');`

Comment: You assign this ```$this->pagination->create_links();``` to ```$data['pagination']```. So instead of echoing ```create_links()```, just ```echo $pagination``` in view.

Comment: @EvinceDevelopment I loaded the pagination library in the autoload file

Comment: @kishor10d its not showing anything when I echo $data['pagination']

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I put `$this->pagination->create_links();` before the `$this->pagination->initialize('$config');`. The create_links() should be after the initialization. It's now showing the pagination links but it's still not updating my pagination links. It's still stuck in page 1.

Comment: @a_simple_traveler: you need to ```echo $pagination``` in view. ```$data['pagination']``` will not work.

Comment: @kishor10d I echoed `$pagination` in view, pagination link still doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using the wrong element ID?

`pagination X paginator`?

```
<div id="pagination"> </div>
```

```
$('#pagination') /* .... */
```